# Different behavior for page.evaluate and page.$ with a follow up function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a page that I load. The following `page.$eval()` code works:

```
const productName = await page.$eval('h1[role="main"]', el =>
    [].reduce.call(
      el.childNodes,
      (a, b) =>
        a +
        (b.nodeType === 3
          ? b.textContent
              .replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, "")
              .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
              .trim()
          : ""),
      ""
    )
  );
```

By works, I mean it returns the intended product name. I run it in the main function.

I now want to outsource the code to its own function outside the original context (to be reused).

I call the function inside the main function like this:

```
  const productName = await page
    .$('h1[role="main"]')
    .then(el => getProductNameFromSelector(el))
    .catch(err => console.log("failure product name", err));
```

The outsourced function is like this:

```
const getProductNameFromSelector = async el =>
  el
    .evaluate(
      el,
      [].reduce.call(
        el.childNodes,
        (a, b) =>
          a +
          (b.nodeType === 3
            ? b.textContent
                .replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, "")
                .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
                .trim()
            : ""),
        ""
      )
    )
    .then(result => result)
    .catch(err => console.log("error in function", err, el));
```

It runs into the following error:

```
failure product name TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluate' of null
    at reduce (<anonymous>)
    at getProductNameFromSelector (pathToFile.js:395:17)
    at page.$.then.el (pathToFile.js:119:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I should be receiving an `ElementHandle` from `page.$('h1[role="main"]')`. It says `undefined` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `evaluate` function needs to expect the `el`ement as an argument

```
const getProductNameFromSelector = async el =>
  el
    .evaluate(el =>  //HERE
      [].reduce.call(
        el.childNodes,
        (a, b) =>
          a +
          (b.nodeType === 3
            ? b.textContent
                .replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, "")
                .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
                .trim()
            : ""),
        ""
      )
    )
    .then(result => result)
    .catch(err => console.log("error in function", err, el));
```

You can also wait for the selector:

```js
const productName = await page
    .waitForSelector('h1[role="main"]')
    .then(el => getProductNameFromSelector(el))
    .catch(err => console.log("failure product name", err));
```

Comment: Thanks, first of all. I've tried it and changed it, but I receive a similar error `failure product name TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluate' of null`.

Comment: Added the changes to the main question, because I still receive the error.

Comment: I must have made another mistake when copying your code, because it works with the original function (i.e. `$()` not `waitForSelector`) as well. Apologies for this and thank you very much for the help!